# PHPexcel cell caching

Tags: php, caching, phpexcel

Am working with large excel file I have removed limits is there a way I can read through my cells much quicker. I have 6000 rows and reducing the tmp folder in my wamp folder.

```
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
include'../Classes/PHPExcel.php';
include'../Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
$cacheMethod = PHPExcel_CachedObjectStorageFactory::cache_to_phpTemp;
$cacheSettings =    array( ' memoryCacheSize ' =>'8MB');    
PHPExcel_Settings::setCacheStorageMethod($cacheMethod, $cacheSettings);
$objReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007();
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load('Book1.xlsx');
$highestRowEM = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestRow();
echo $highestRowEM;
for($i=0;$i<$highestRowEM;$i++){
    $varval=$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A'.$i)->getValue();
    if($varval==""){
        break;
    }
}
echo $i;
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('Book1.xlsx');
```

What to clean up workbooks with worksheets with , in them

```
  `include'../Classes/PHPExcel.php';
  include'../Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
  set_time_limit(0);
  ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
  $xlsxfiles=$_SESSION['file'];
  echo $xlsxfiles;
  echo "<br>";
  $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
  $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load('../upload/'.$xlsxfiles);
  $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, "Excel2007");
  ////Validation
  foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) {
      $highestRow = $worksheet-> getHighestDataRow();
      $columnhighest=$worksheet->getHighestDataColumn();
      $columnhighestval=array_search($columnhighest, $alphabet);
      echo 'Worksheet - ' , $worksheet->getTitle()." Number of rows: ".$highestRow."<br>";
      for($cl=0;$cl<$highestRow+1;$cl++){
          for ($ga=1;$ga<$columnhighestval;$ga++){
              $letters=strtoupper($alphabet[$ga]);
              $clean=$worksheet->getCell($letters.$cl)->getValue();
              $cleandone=str_replace(','," ",$clean);
              $worksheet->setCellValue($letters.$cl,$cleandone);
          }
          $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
      }
  }
  $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, "Excel2007");
  $objWriter->setOffice2003Compatibility(true);
  $objWriter->save('../upload/'.$xlsxfiles);
  echo "Done";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tip 1:

replace

```
for($i=0;$i<$highestRowEM;$i++){
    $varval=$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A'.$i)->getValue();
```

with

```
$objSheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
for($i=0;$i<$highestRowEM;$i++){
    $varval = $objSheet->getCell('A'.$i)->getValue();
```

Then you're not calling $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet() in every iteration of the loop.

Then tell us what you're actually trying to do with the worksheet data, and we may be able to help speed it up a bit more

**EDIT**

Don't set the cell value unless you have to; 
Don't instantiate the Writer until you need it, and definitely not in the loop;
Instead of using $letters and $alphabet, use the routines built-into PHPExcel, or take advantage of PHP's Perl-style character incrementor;
Don't do maths in your loop comparisons

```
  ////Validation
  foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) {
      $highestRow = $worksheet->getHighestDataRow();
      $columnhighest=$worksheet->getHighestDataColumn();
      $columnhighest++;
      echo 'Worksheet - ' , $worksheet->getTitle()." Number of rows: ".$highestRow."<br>";
      for($cl = 0; $cl <= $highestRow; $cl++){
          for ($ga='A'; $ga !== $columnhighest; $ga++){
              $clean=$worksheet->getCell($ga.$cl)->getValue();
              $cleandone=str_replace(','," ",$clean);
              if($clean != $cleandone) {
                  $worksheet->setCellValue($ga.$cl, $cleandone);
              }
          }
      }
  }
  $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
```

Comment: When I get the highest number of rows it gives me 6000. But I have data only upto 1700. Anything beyond 1700 are blank rows is there a way i can delete the rows beyond and reduce how long it take to go through all the rows with data. My tmp file in wamp goes up to 20gb.

Comment: PHPExcel doesn't delete rows at present, just empties cell so they still remain in the workbook.... but you can use $highestRowEM = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestDataRow(); instead of $highestRowEM = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestRow(); to find the last row conatining actual data content. getHighestRow() makes allowance for a whole host of other situations, such as cells with formatting but no data.

Comment: Its still taking long to process and adding more disk space. I just added in the getHighestDataRow just to read the file but its still adding in more space in the tmp and it has shown my results when I used a file with 41 lines and it gave me the result. Is there another way I can compress the file.

Comment: You can't compress the file unless you do so in MS Excel. PHPExcel isn't quick, it's doing a lot of work; and the volume of data in the file still has to be stored somewhere, even when its cached. Most people working with large volumes of data use background processes to handle it. You still haven't shown what you're doing with the data you read: it might be possible to speed things up there.

Comment: Am cleaning up cells that have , in a work book with multiple worksheets.<br>

Comment: Well there may be ways to simplify that process: for example, are you doing a setCellValue regardless of whether a cell contained a comma or not?

Comment: I have added the code above. All its doing is opening a workbook with worksheets and removing any , and replacing it with a blank space.

Comment: that os correct whether or it if it contains a comma or not. is there another method i could try?